# PostgreSQL: Dynamic WHERE criteria for query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a project where I need to create dynamic query filter rules within a table, to be used to filter data in another table.  I am in need of some assistance to see whether this is viable, and if so, how the query might be formed.

```
       people                                rules
+----+--------+-----+     +----+--------+-------+----------+----------+
| id |  name  | age |     | id |  type  | field | operator | criteria |
+----+--------+-----+     +----+--------+-------+----------+----------+
|  1 | Emma   |  34 |     |  1 | people | age   | >        | 30       |
|  2 | Larry  |  25 |     +----+--------+-------+----------+----------+
|  3 | Alice  |  22 |
|  4 | Thomas |  31 |
+----+--------+-----+
```

In this example, I want to query the "people" table by the using the criteria in the "rules" table.  I read about Common Table Expressions in PostgreSQL and thought I could potentially use it here, but thus far I've not been successful.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
WITH    cte_rule AS (SELECT field FROM rules WHERE id = 1)
SELECT  *,
FROM    people
WHERE   (SELECT field FROM cte_rule) < 30;
```

This results in the following error returned from the database:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying < integer
LINE 4: WHERE (SELECT field FROM cte_rule) < 30;
                                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm trying to hard-code some of the values for now, and if successful with making part of the statement dynamic, then further extend it to be completely dynamic.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In SQL identifiers (database objects, table columns) and the data are different entities and are not interchangeable. So there's no feature like "take the value from this column and turn it to identifier" withour dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can use a stored procedure to dynamically build the SQL as a string and then EXECUTE this string (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: And the reason why it is not possible is simple: SQL statement processing consists of some arbitrary steps, that include statement parsing (because SQL is declarative), when parser checks that your statement have a valid structure and uses existing identifiers to build a query plan: which objects should be accessed with which access type and which predicates. And all this is done at the very beginning.

Comment: Ah okay.  Thanks @astentx

Comment: @astentx: it turns this is actually possible without dynamic SQL ;)

Answer (score 5):

You will need dynamic SQL for this.

As both, the values **and** column names are dynamic and also the context in which they are applied this is a bit tricky.

Something along the lines:

```
create or replace function evaluate_rule(p_row record, p_rule_id int)
  returns boolean
as
$$
declare
  l_expression text;
  l_rule rules;
  l_result boolean;
  l_values jsonb;
  l_type text;
begin
  
  select *
    into l_rule
  from rules
  where id = p_rule_id
    and type = pg_typeof(p_row)::text;
  
  if not found then 
    return false;
  end if;
  
  l_values := to_jsonb(p_row);
  l_type := jsonb_typeof(l_values -> l_rule.field);
  
  if l_type = 'number' then 
    l_expression := format('select %s %s %s', l_values ->> l_rule.field, l_rule.operator, l_rule.criteria);
  else 
    l_expression := format('select %L %s %L', l_values ->> l_rule.field, l_rule.operator, l_rule.criteria);
  end if;
  
  execute l_expression 
    into l_result;
    
  return l_result;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
stable;
```

Unfortunately, the conversion to JSONB in order to dynamically pick column values from the passed row does make you lose the data type information. But I can't really think of a different way to dynamically create an expression where the column names and values are not known beforehand.

If a rule specifies a column that doesn't exist, this would result in an expression like `NULL > 42` which will evaluate as false.

The function assumes that there is exactly one rule for the combination of "type" and "id". If you don't care about whether the requested rule matches the passed table, you can remove the condition `and type = pg_typeof(p_row)::text`

Given this sample data:

```
create table rules (id int,   type  text, field text, operator text, criteria text);
insert into rules values 
(1, 'people', 'age', '>', '30'), 
(2, 'people', 'name', '=', 'Alice');


create table people (id int, name text, age int);
insert into people
values
  (1, 'Emma', 34),
  (2, 'Larry', 25),
  (3, 'Alice', 22),
  (4, 'Thomas', 31)
;
```

You can use it like this:

```
select p.*
from people p
where evaluate_rule(p, 1)

id | name   | age
---+--------+----
 1 | Emma   |  34
 4 | Thomas |  31
```

Of with the second rule:

```
select p.*
from people p
where evaluate_rule(p, 2)

id | name  | age
---+-------+----
 3 | Alice |  22
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e7c1874e2922db2316d68ab60a161334)

---

**Edit**

It just occurred to me, that with Postgres 12 or later, this can actually be done without dynamic SQL or a helper function:

```
with cte_rule as (
  select (concat('$.', field, ' ', operator, ' ', criteria))::jsonpath as rule
  from rules
  where id = 1
)
select p.*
from people p
where to_jsonb(p) @@ (select rule from cte_rule);
```

The operator needs to comply with the rules for [SQL/JSON path language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH), e.g. you need to use `==` instead of `=` and double quotes for strings. So my second example rule would need to be:

```
insert into rules values 
(2, 'people', 'name', '==', '"Alice"');
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ed1a520e3e03abe09ff3f095664d4b04)

---

If using JSON path is an alternative you might want to think about storing the final expression in a single column rather than column name, operator and value in three different columns.

Storing the expression in a `jsonpath` column has the benefit, that the syntax will be parsed and validated when you try to store the expression.

```
create table rules (id int, type  text, expression jsonpath);
insert into rules values 
(1, 'people', '$.age > 30'), 
(2, 'people', '$.name == "Alice"');
```

Then you can use:

```
select p.*
from people p
where to_jsonb(p) @@ (select expression from rules where id = 1)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8297949b5d907c9db074063c39aaf79)